# How to I click the right day on DatePicker in selenium?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I meet a problem with selenium test like this: I have a page with the date picker to select the date. My test must click on the right day (ex: 14/2/2012). Unfortunately, the date picker is created by Jquery as code below:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the .SendKeys("") to set the value. It's still only a textfield under the hood